# Enable and Popup blocker in IE

Tags: javascript

I wrote a scripting logic in using ActiveX. When the application runs it is blocked by popup blocker. When I enabled it works fine, but I want to enable the popupblocker using JavaScript (especially in IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. What you could do is have a message on screen which requests the user to turn off the popup blocker .

Answer (score 4):

Obviously a website cannot modify the popup blocker settings. And that's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using ActiveX Controls because it is only supported by IE. Trying running your page on Firefox and it won't work.

Now the actual problem - 
Firstly you need to understand what ActiveX Objects are used for? They basically allow a web application to interact with the client machine. For example it can use resources on my local hard drive. This is a security risk. So IE gives a warning for the same. You may disable it in your browser by going to Tools-> Internet Options -> Security Tab. Click "Custom Level" and change all the boxes with ActiveX text in it to "Enable".
But it will still show up in your client browsers.
So the point is try finding an alternative for it.

Hope this helps!